# How to make TMaskEdit a multiline edit in Delphi XE2

Tags: forms, delphi, controls, edit, mask

I need the functionality of multi-line to be added to my TMaskEdit, I can locate the property responsible for this feature. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a TMaskEdit multiline, adding the [`ES_MULTILINE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Style to the control via overriding the [`CreateParams`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateParams) method. Like so

```
type

  TMaskEdit = class(Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit)
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

  TForm30 = class(TForm)
    MaskEdit1: TMaskEdit;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form30: TForm30;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TMaskEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
const Alignments: array[TAlignment] of Longint =
      (ES_LEFT, ES_RIGHT, ES_CENTER);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
                                  //Multiline        //scrollbars
  Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_MULTILINE or WS_HSCROLL or WS_VSCROLL;
end;

procedure TForm30.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MaskEdit1.Height:= 250;
 MaskEdit1.AutoSize:= False;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this is different from a TMemo. It does not result in a single line Edit with wrapped text across multiple lines, but basically a TMemo without the useful word wrap and scroll bar configuration properties. But, technically, it answers the question posed.